# In Semantic UI, when should one include the 'ui' class?

Tags: semantic-ui

I was surprised to find that

```
  <h2 class="ui header">
    <i class="ui comment icon"></i>
    <div class="ui content">
      rofl
      <div class="sub header">foo bar</div>
    </div>
  </h2>
```

Is different from

```
  <h2 class="ui header">
    <i class="ui comment icon"></i>
    <div class="ui content">
      rofl
      <div class="ui sub header">foo bar</div>
    </div>
  </h2>
```

which is identical except for having `ui sub header` instead of just `sub header`.

`sub header` gives 'foo bar'.

`ui sub header` for some reason gives us 'FOO BAR' (all caps).

**I realized that I really don't understand what the 'ui' class does. What does it do?**

Answer (score 0):

It's just a default styles of this css class(sub) in semantic-ui for all sub-header elements.

here you can read more information about of it:
 [styles of sub-header in semantic-ui](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/header.html#sub-headers)

Comment: More generally, what does the `ui` class do?